# Get-WmiObject:“Provider not found” (0x80041013)

Tags: wmi, get-wmiobject

Before I'll tell you the problem, I'd like to mention that I'm new to WMI.

In fact, the problem is that when I execute the query "get-wmiobject -namespace root\snmp\SMIR SNMP_JVM_MANAGEMENT_MIB_jvmMemory"
from PowerShell, I get this error “Provider not found” (error number "0x80041013"). 
But even when using other classes belonging to the namespace "root\snmp\SMIR" , the same error occurs.

I tried to google the issue and I found a Microsoft Link (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406382.aspx#H27) which describes some steps I must follow,
yet when I tried these steps and even when i rebuild the Wmi Repository, the error persists as well.

Please i need your help!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Check which namespaces you have available.
`get-wmiobject -namespace "root" -class "__Namespace" | Select Name`

Is the namespace you are looking for in this list?

Have you tried any other namespaces?
Like for example.

`get-wmiobject -namespace root\cimv2 -list`

`Try get-wmiobject -class win32_bios`
Do you get the same error?

Comment: Thank you Martin for your response.
 Actually, I tried "get-wmiobject -class win32_bios" but I don't get the same error. Otherwise, when I run the "get-wmiobject -namespace "root" -class "__Namespace" | Select Name", the "snmp" namespace exists in the list. 
Thanks a lot again !